# Is $\sin 2x$ the same thing as $2\sin x$?

Tags: trigonometry

Is $\sin2x$ the same thing as $2\sin x$?

I am unsure whether it is valid to bring out the two outside the sine.

Comment: Have you at least tried checking if $\sin 2x = 2\sin x$ for a few nice values of $x$? Try $x = 90^{\circ}$.

Comment: In creative math, of course its valid. I also recommend paying off the US nation debt ($\$17,719,164,324,963$) by summing it's digits and paying off that amount instead. Works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula $\sin 2x = 2\sin x$ is incorrect.

Imagine what this would mean if we had $x = 20^{\circ}$. $\sin 40^{\circ}$ would have to be twice as big as $\sin 20^{\circ}$.

Now draw the unit circle and place the points corresponding to the angles $20^{\circ}$ and $40^{\circ}$. The $y$-coordinates of these points are $\sin 20^{\circ}$ and $\sin 40^{\circ}$ respectively.

But is the second point twice as high above the $x$-axis as the first? No, certainly not.

As you move around the circle from $0^{\circ}$ to $20^{\circ}$ to $40^{\circ}$, the second part of the path is the same length as the first part. But compared to the first part, the second part goes more to the left and doesn't go up as fast. So the second part of the path rises less overall than the first part.

This shows that the sine of $40^{\circ}$ is *less* than twice as big as the sine of $20^{\circ}$, not exactly twice as big.

Comment: It's even more obvious if you consider $x = 90^{\circ}$.

Comment: Yes, but I thought the argument might be more understandable for acute angles, since these are generally more familiar. Also, you can see that the formula is *almost* true for small angles, which I think is interesting.

Comment: @Dave: That's because for small angles $\sin(x) \approx x$.

Answer (score 0):

$\sin(2x)\ne2\sin(x)$

We can write $\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$ after some simplification of the double angle formula.

Obviously, $2\sin(x)\cos(x)\ne2\sin(x)$ and therefore $\sin(2x)\ne2\sin(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

No, the two are not the same. Example could be (2)(sin 2pi/3)= (2)(sort(3)/2)= sqrt(3) while sin(2x) would be sin((2)(2pi/3))= sin(4pi/3)= - sqrt(3)/2

Answer (score 0):

No. In general, for a function $f,$ we have $$f(ax) \neq af(x) \quad,$$ (unless the function is [linear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_function#As_a_linear_map) , which $\sin$ is **not**).

You can verify that $\sin(2x) \neq 2\sin(x)$ by substituting, for example, $x=10$ and showing that $\text{LHS} \neq \text{RHS}.$

Comment: The condition $f(ax) = a f(x)$ is homogeneity of degree 1 (which linear functions are, but in general, not all functions which are homogeneous of degree 1 are linear).